# Modified JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I am returning a list from my database table. The code for it is as follows:

```
public List<Album> GetAlbums()
            {
                List<Album> Albums = new List<Album>();
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("GetAlbums", con);
                    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Albums.Add(new Album { id = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetValue(0)), name = dr.GetValue(1).ToString().Trim(), artist = dr.GetValue(2).ToString().Trim() });
                    }
                }
                return Albums;
            }
```

The above function is returning a JSON string since it is written inside a restful WCF service. The format of the JSON string is as follows:

```
{"GetAlbumResult":[{"artist":"Kanjoliya","id":128,"name":"Gopal"},{"artist":"Kapoor","id":143,"name":"Lalit"},{"artist":"Ayachit","id":138,"name":"Madhukar"},{"artist":"Chouhan","id":142,"name":"Manish"}]}
```

What I actually want is string in the following format:

```
{"results":100,"GetAlbumResult":[{"artist":"Kanjoliya","id":128,"name":"Gopal"},{"artist":"Kapoor","id":143,"name":"Lalit"},{"artist":"Ayachit","id":138,"name":"Madhukar"},{"artist":"Chouhan","id":142,"name":"Manish"}]}
```

in the above string the "results" property is to be returned from stored procedure. I need that for paging in the gridview. What changes do I have to make in my code and/or sql procedure? Curently my procedure is just a select * from .... statement.

Comment: well, you'll need an `IEnumerable<Album>` with a `Results` property or, you'll need to change the serialiser to take the `List.Count` and serialise it as `results`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have return type something like this in your implementation, so that results will have count of records and GetAlbumResult will have result from procedure. You don't need to change stored procedure.

```
class Result
{
  public int results {get;set;}
  public List<Album> GetAlbumResult { get; set;}
}
```